# how stop cassandra embedded server in junit tests

Tags: java, junit, cassandra

I'm using embedded cassandra server in unit tests. If I run junit tests separate everything is ok and tests done without fail. But when I build application with maven (maven install) I get this error before second test file

> ERROR me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager - Out of order in HConnectionManager shutdown()?: shutdown() called for inactive pool: :{127.0.0.1(127.0.0.1):9272}

I mean it's because cassandra server isn't down and is still running. It is something like that https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/pull/39

Can you help me with that? How can I close cassandra server correctly between test files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing Cassandra server you should try re-creating the database. That is what Playorm is also doing in its test. You can have a look at

https://github.com/deanhiller/playorm/blob/master/src/test/java/com/alvazan/test/TestIndexes.java

So, you can see that they are using @Before and @After annotations to create and drop the database.

Comment: I use `@BeforeClass` to start and `@AfterClass` to stop the cassandra server in test files. I edited my question a little bit, look at it again please.